# Probability of drawing $5$ white and $4$ black balls and another bag of $7$ white and $9$ black balls.

Tags: probability

**Question:**

A bag contains $5$ white and $4$ black balls and another bag contains $7$ white and $9$ black balls . A ball is drawn from the first bag and two balls are drawn from the second bag. What is the probability of drawing one white and two black balls?

**My Approach:**

Case $1$: 1 white ball from bag $1$ and $2$ balls from bag $2$ . So probability is $$\frac{\binom{5}{1}\times \binom{9}{2}}{\binom{9}{1}\times\binom{16}{2}}$$

Case $2$: *I can't understand how to solve this part.*

Comment: So the bags are chosen randomly as well?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I don't know.May be.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma wait you are right.Yes i have mentioned that in case 1.

Comment: So the other case is 1 ball from the second bag (7/9) and 2 from the other? Then take the average of these  2 probabilities.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma case 2 should be I think 1 black ball from bag 1 and 1 white ball and 1 black ball from bag 2.

Comment: Try using `\binom{5}{1}` or `{5\choose1}` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's draw from the first bag at first.

Then:

$$P(wbb)+P(bbw)+P(bwb)=\frac59\frac9{16}\frac8{15}+\frac49\frac9{16}\frac7{15}+\frac49\frac7{16}\frac9{15}$$

where e.g. $bwb$ stands for the event that at first a black ball is drawn (from the first bag) secondly a white ball (from the second bag) and thirdly a black ball (from the second bag).

Comment: The answer given in my book is 1/6(case1)+7/30(case2)=2/5.

Comment: Can you just check it once.

Comment: That's also my answer (as you can check yourself).

Comment: Yes thanks for answering

Comment: You are welcome.